# Почему message sender для bot telegram выполняется несколько раз?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, sendmessage, multiple

Я создал бота в телеграмме.
Установил webhook к файлу хостинга.

Вот php файл:

```
<?php
    include_once '../simple_html_dom.php';

    global $connect;
    $connect=new mysqli("localhost","","","");
    $connect->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

    $string_input = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $string_input = json_decode($string_input);

    $text=$string_input->{'message'}->{'text'};

    if ($text=="start"){
        sendMessage(1);
        first($connect);
        sendMessage(2);
        second($connect);
        sendMessage(3);
        third($connect);
        sendMessage(4);
    }


    function first(connect){...}    


    function second(connect){...}


    function third(connect){...}



    function sendMessage($i) {
        $chatID="...";
        $token="...";

        $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $token . "/sendMessage?chat_id=" . $chatID;
        $url = $url . "&text=" . urlencode($i);
        $ch = curl_init();
        $optArray = array(
                CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
        );
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $optArray);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }
?>
```

Bot:

```
               ~ start  

1
2
3
4
1
3
2
4
1
2
3
3
1
4
2
1
2
```

В чем причина, и как его исправить? подскажите пожалуйста...

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри лог веб сервера, когда получаешь первое сообщение от сервера telegram. HTTP код в твоем случае, скорее всего отличный от 200 . Сервер telegram не получив 200 HTTP код об успешной доставке сообщения, делает повторную попытку доставить это-же сообщение. Снова получает отличный от 200 HTTP код и так далее.
 Также причина может быть в том, что слишком долго на твоем сервере обрабатывается запрос от сервера telegram. Не дождавшись ответа, сервер telegram сбрасывает соединение и пытается повторить доставку сообщения. 
 
Получается бесконечный цикл.

Здесь нужно добавить:

```
if ($text=="start"){
    sendMessage(1);
    first($connect);
    sendMessage(2);
    second($connect);
    sendMessage(3);
    third($connect);
    sendMessage(4);
    return 'ok';
}
```

Другой способ решения - использовать асинхронную отправку сообщений (функция sendmessage), например через очередь.